# how to evaluate condition based on cookie in nginx with cookies being removed from the request

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

With nginx proxy_pass configuration, we are removing the cookies using

```
proxy_hide_header               Set-Cookie;
proxy_ignore_headers            Set-Cookie;
proxy_set_header                Cookie "";
```

Can we still evaluate the condition using cookie in nginx for redirecting the request if particular cookie is present or missing?

I want to evaluate if particular cookie is present in upstream response then I need to do redirect or else let the request do the proxy_pass.

How would I do that?

Comment: Do you mean _if particular cookie is present or missing in the client request_ or _if particular cookie is present or missing in the upstream response_?

Comment: if particular cookie is present in upstream response... i updated the question

Comment: So you want to decide should the request be passed to the upstream or should it be redirected analyzing the upstream response? Analyzing the upstream response **before** passing the request to the upstream??? Doesn't it look like a nonsense to you?

Comment: so we get the response from the upstream, we check the condition based on its response, and only if it match the particular condition, instead of passing the request.. we redirect it to other location.